# Grails 2.2 Integration test fails when using withNewSession

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I'm migrating from grails 1.3.6 to 2.2.4.  I'm currently having issues using withNewSession during an integration test.  I've set up a demo project to more clearly represent the issue.  Code Below:

```
class DomainA {
String id
String domainB
String description

static constraints =
{
    id unique: true, nullable:false
    domainB (nullable: false, blank:false,
    validator:{val, obj ->
        if(val != null)
        {
            DomainA.withNewSession{session ->
                def result = DomainB.findByDescription(val)
                if(result == null)
                {
                    return  'foreignkey'
                }
            }
        }

    })
}

static mapping =
{
    table 'DOMAIN_A'
    id column:'id', type: 'string', generator: 'assigned'
    version false
    domainB column:'DOMAIN_B'
}

}



class DomainB {

String id
String description

static constraints =
{
    id unique: true, nullable:false
    description nullable:false
}
static mapping =
{
    table 'DOMAIN_B'
    id column:'id', type: 'string', generator: 'assigned'
    version false
}
}
```

And the integration test

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.*
class WithNewSessionTestTests extends GroovyTestCase{

@Before
void setUp() {
    DomainB b = new DomainB(description:"BEE")
    b.id = "B"
    b.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    DomainA a = new DomainA(domainB:"BEE", description:"EHH")
    a.id = "A"
    a.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
}
@Test
void testSomething() {
    assertTrue true
}
}
```

The test fails when `a` tries to save.  The error code coming back is 'foreignkey', which is what is returned when `DomainA` can't find an instance of `DomainB`.  Debugging also shows me that the result value of `DomainB.findByDescription(val)` is `null`.  Any ideas on how to get around this?  I want my tests to continue to be transactional to avo

This test will succeed if I either remove `withNewSession` from the validation or if I set the test to `static transactional = false`.  Any ideas on how to preserve both the withNewSession call and the transactional nature of the test?

Versions:  Grails 2.2.4, Oracle 10+, Java 7.0.21, groovy 2.0.7

Comment: Hey, I am currently upgrading from Grails 136 to 224. Was this working fine in 136? Also whats the thought behind using NewSession vs using the same session in the validator? Will you not face the same issue at run time?

Comment: It was working fine in 1.3.6.  You don't get the issue at run time, only during integration tests.  The reason I've been using withNewSession was to avoid hibernate flushing before the `find` is executed.  Flushing while calling the custom validator creates an infinite loop/stack overflow error.

Comment: Can you try wrapping domainB save with withTransaction{..}?

Comment: Wrapping in `withTransaction{...}` doesn't change its behavior at all.

Comment: Why isn't the Integration test class inheriting `GroovyTestCase`?

Comment: @dmahapatro - Just a copy paste omission.  I fixed the post.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    class DomainA {
String id
String domainB
String description
----- rest of the code
}
```

to

```
class DomainA {
String id
DomainB domainB
String description
}
```

In Integration Test

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.*
class WithNewSessionTestTests extends GroovyTestCase{

@Before
void setUp() {
    DomainB b = new DomainB(description:"BEE")
    b.id = "B"
    b.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    DomainA a = new DomainA(domainB:b, description:"EHH")
    a.id = "A"
    a.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
}
@Test
void testSomething() {
    assertTrue true
}
}
```

This should work.

**Edit**

From [Grails Integration Test](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting)

> Integration tests run inside a database transaction by default, which
>   is rolled back at the end of the each test. This means that data saved
>   during a test is not persisted to the database. Add a transactional
>   property to your test class to check transactional behaviour:

```
 class MyServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    static transactional = false
     void testMyTransactionalServiceMethod() {
         …
    } }
```

> Be sure to remove any persisted data from a non-transactional test,
>   for example in the tearDown method, so these tests don't interfere
>   with standard transactional tests that expect a clean database.

Without `static transactional = false` then the test would have to persist to the db, and in integration test, data are rolledback and not persisted to the database.

Comment: This doesn't solve the underlying issue of retaining transactional behavior without changing the underlying application code.  There are other cases within my project where WithNewSession is used that need to be tested.  This is just a simple example to demonstrate the failure.